# How to explain to laypeople that in a VAR model some variable explaines its own variance?

Tags: time-series, variance, vector-autoregression, variance-decomposition

Background: 
I observed that people not familiar with vector autoregressive (VAR) models often struggle with the interpretation of a forecast error variance decomposition. I am frequently asked, why a variable is able to explain a share of its own variance and I don't have a good explanation.

**My question: Do you have an idea how to explain this issue in easy terms?**

Here is an example: I fitted a VAR(1) model with the variables `prod` (labour productivity) and `e` (employment).

$prod_t = a_{01} + a_{11}prod_{t-1} + a_{12}e_{t-1} + w_{t1}$

$e_t \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,= a_{02} + a_{21}prod_{t-1} + a_{22}e_{t-1} + w_{t2}$

On the following picture, the forecast error variance decomposition for both variables are shown. As it can be seen, `e` is explaining part of its own FE variance. From a theoretical point of view, this makes sense because of the autoregressive structure of the system. But what might be a good explanation for a layman? Can I say, $e$'s share of variance caputures the variance that is not explained by other variables?

[image: Plot 1]
Code in R:

```
require(vars)
data(Canada)
var.2c <- VAR(Canada[,1:2], p = 2, type = "const")
plot(fevd(var.2c, n.ahead = 10))
```